# how to paint text on RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Syntax Highlight in a RichTextBox [C#]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697360/how-to-syntax-highlight-in-a-richtextbox-c)

How do I paint in any "select" or "where" word green and any number in red when typing in a RichTextBox?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the property of RichTextbox "Selectioncolor":

```
richTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
```

Answer (score 0):

The main princip to word highlighting in RichTextBox box consist of steps:

1. Find out start position of the word
2. Find out length of the word
3. Select word by its start position and length (you should use SelectionStart and SelectionLength properties of RichTextBox)
4. Managing selected word appearance by manipulations with SelectionFont, SelectionColor, SelectioStyle properties of your RichTextBox