# Separate color for each line in asp:TextBox

Tags: asp.net, richtextbox, code-formatting

I want to create an IDE in .NET for some programming language for that I need an input textbox where I will have space to write my code. In this textbox I need a code formatter like if a specific line contains a word `imports` that line must have red color, if a code contains words like `public, private, protected, internal` that line must be in green color. Somewhat in this model if some word is detected that line should get a color. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Not possible with the standard TextBox(edit: but just found [this approach](http://www.queness.com/post/10363/10-feature-packed-javascript-wysiwyg-and-rich-text-editors), try it). You could use one of these controls:  http://www.queness.com/post/10363/10-feature-packed-javascript-wysiwyg-and-rich-text-editors

Comment: @TimSchmelter those are javascript, OP wanted a .net program.

Comment: @jzworkman: i've misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to be using a RichTextBox and then you can find your keywords and highlight the entire line they are on by setting the background color of the richTextBox for that line.  Look at this answer for richTextBox syntax highlighting, it should point you in the right direction : [How to Syntax Highlight in a RichTextBox [C#]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697360/how-to-syntax-highlight-in-a-richtextbox-c)