# Showing a VBA Script Text Block/Box in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to show VBA text editor in a Visual C# Windows App.  I want the user to open a vba script in my app and I want the native vba script editor to display.

Does anyone know where I can get ahold of this kind of script editor?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a good site for asking for tool suggestions. What have you tried so far? I don't think you can easily get the native script editor. Why not using a syntax highlighted text box?

Comment: Try Scintilla.NET (taken from this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087735/a-textbox-richtextbox-that-has-syntax-highlighting-c))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use Hosted workflow.