# Change color of specific word in drawstring image?

Tags: c#

I am use Graphics.DrawString for writing text on image bellow is my code

```
 graphicsImage.DrawString(message, new Font("arial", 15, FontStyle.Regular), new SolidBrush(StringColor), drawRect);
```

I am wrap the text content by using rectangle f. now i want change color specific word. how can i do that ?

Comment: You must draw it separately.

Comment: "hey welcome how are you" that is my sentence which i draw. so how can change welcome color. is this not possible

Comment: You must draw `hey` in one color, `welcome` in another and then `how are you` probably in the same color as `hey`. Unfortunately you cannot do this with 1 call to DrawString which means you need to take on the word wrapping logic yourself.

Comment: you have any idea for this

Comment: No, doing proper word wrapping is a complex topic and not up my alley. All I can tell you is that you won't be able to do it with one call to DrawString, nor do I think there is any good alternative in the .NET framework.

Comment: how about using a `RichTextBox`. Then you could look at [this helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21980957/5174469) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1926822/5174469)

Comment: i am not use ritchtextbox

Comment: @jaipundir I understand that. That was a suggesttion. Because it would make the parsing of the string and drawing certain words in certain colours much easier

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly! - Other than that: Yes, it is work, tedious work. Btw, while not easier you should use TextTenderer for better quality..

Comment: console application c#