# Check if user typed specific word after typing the word, in an <Editor>

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So what I'm looking for is a code which will check if the user wrote one of the specific words (Select, From, Where). If true, then the textcolor of that word must change (TextChanged event). I don't know how I have to make it so, that it is possible.

I'm using `Xamarin.Forms` and made in the `Page.xaml` the following code:

```
<Editor x:Name="qEditor" 
     Text="Input"
     TextChanged="Handle_TextChanged"
     BackgroundColor="White" 
     HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
     HeightRequest="75"/>
```

So whenever someone typed one of the specific words, the color of only that word must directly change to red.

Code in `Page.xaml.cs`:

```
void Handle_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string input = e.NewTextValue;
    string[] qInput = input.Split(' ');
    //Code here
}
```

I looked a lot around on Google and Stackoverflow and [found something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21980554/color-specific-words-in-richtextbox), but it uses `Contains` which did not work for my code.

If you have any suggestions of what I need to change or even if I have to change everything about the code above, give me some suggestions. The project requires me to only work with `C#` And `Xamarin.Forms`.

Comment: I hope [this](https://alexdunn.org/2017/03/07/xamarin-controls-creating-your-own-markdown-textblock-in-uwp/) could help you.

Comment: It looks very useful, but I forgot to mention that I don't work with `Html` only with `C#` and `Xamarin.Foms`.

Comment: yeah I know that. It's just showing the approach. Your's looks like you want to show `SQL` or sth similar. It's just a guidiance. In WPF there is `<Run />`in a `RitchTextBox` but I don't think there is anything similar in `Xamarin` yet.

Comment: Don't think so to, but there must be something for `C#` which will work with the `Xamarin.Forms` part. And yes, I want to make a `QueryTool`.

Comment: I think this could also be done with a Xamarin Behavior. See [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/behaviors/creating/)

Comment: What do you mean "Contains" does not work?

Comment: When I used `Contains` the code did see the word(s) constantly, so it changed all the text to the color red, even when I did not type the words I want to change color. @Jason

Comment: @M.D. I tried to figure it out, but don't really understand the way it works.

Comment: Still ... the link i provided shows exactly how to implement behaviours ...

Comment: why don't you show us what you tried so that we can help you fix it, rather than ask us to write something from scratch for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xamarin forms doesn't support this out of the box.

You will have to extend the `Editor` control to add support for formatted-text. This can be done by adding a bindable property of type `FormattedString`. This control will keep the property updated by listening to text changes through `TextChanged` event (I have used `Regex` in this case).

As `FormattedText` will be bindable-property, the custom platform renderers can detect the change, and accordingly render it as `Spannable` in android and `AttributedString` in iOS.

[image]

### Forms Control

```
public class ExEditor : Editor
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty FormattedTextProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            "FormattedText", typeof(FormattedString), typeof(ExEditor),
            defaultValue: default(FormattedString));

    public FormattedString FormattedText
    {
        get { return (FormattedString)GetValue(FormattedTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FormattedTextProperty, value); }
    }

    public ExEditor()
    {
        TextChanged += ExEditor_TextChanged;
    }

    void ExEditor_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Text))
            return;

        var pattern = @"\b(SELECT|WHERE|AND|OR)\b";
        var words = Regex.Split(Text, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);

        var formattedString = new FormattedString();
        foreach (var word in words)
            formattedString.Spans.Add(new Span
            {
                Text = word,
                BackgroundColor = BackgroundColor,
                FontSize = FontSize,
                FontFamily = FontFamily,
                FontAttributes = FontAttributes,
                ForegroundColor = Regex.IsMatch(word, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) ? Color.Red : TextColor
            });

        FormattedText = formattedString; 
    }       
}
```

### iOS Renderer

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ExEditor), typeof(ExEditorRenderer))]
namespace SampleApp.iOS
{
    public class ExEditorRenderer : EditorRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null || Element == null)
                return;

            UpdateTextOnControl();
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            if (e.PropertyName == nameof(ExEditor.FormattedText)
                || e.PropertyName == nameof(Editor.FontFamily)
                || e.PropertyName == nameof(Editor.FontSize)
                || e.PropertyName == nameof(Editor.TextColor)
                || e.PropertyName == nameof(Editor.BackgroundColor)
                || e.PropertyName == nameof(Editor.FontAttributes))
                {
                    UpdateTextOnControl();
                }
        }

        void UpdateTextOnControl()
        {
            var caretPos = Control.GetOffsetFromPosition(Control.BeginningOfDocument, Control.SelectedTextRange.Start);

            if (Element is ExEditor formsElement)
                if (formsElement.FormattedText != null)
                    Control.AttributedText = formsElement.FormattedText.ToAttributed(new Font(), Element.TextColor);

            var newPosition = Control.GetPosition(Control.BeginningOfDocument, offset: caretPos);
            Control.SelectedTextRange = Control.GetTextRange(newPosition, newPosition);
        }
    }
}
```

### Android Renderer

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ExEditor), typeof(ExEditorRenderer))]
namespace SampleApp.Android
{
    public class ExEditorRenderer : EditorRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null || Element == null)
                return;

            UpdateTextOnControl();
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            if (e.PropertyName == nameof(ExEditor.FormattedText)
                || e.PropertyName == nameof(Editor.FontFamily)
                || e.PropertyName == nameof(Editor.FontSize)
                || e.PropertyName == nameof(Editor.TextColor)
                || e.PropertyName == nameof(Editor.BackgroundColor)
                || e.PropertyName == nameof(Editor.FontAttributes))
            {
                UpdateTextOnControl();
            }
        }

        void UpdateTextOnControl()
        {
            var caretPos = Control.SelectionStart;

            if (Element is ExEditor formsElement)
                if (formsElement.FormattedText != null)
                    Control.SetText(formsElement.FormattedText.ToAttributed(new Font(), Element.TextColor, Control),
                                    TextView.BufferType.Spannable);

            Control.SetSelection(caretPos);
        }
    }
}
```

### Sample Usage

```
<!-- make sure to map local prefix to control's namespace -->
<local:ExEditor Text="Select * from Table where text='1' and type='str'" 
        VerticalOptions="Start" />
```

Comment: Maybe you know why, I added some extra words, like 20 extra words, but some of them I can not highlight.. @G.Sharada

Comment: If should technically be highlighted if Regex is working

Comment: A lot of the words do, but some of them don't. Like `Add`, `Round`, `Drop` and `GROUP BY`, but `ORDER BY` is highlighted and a lot of the others.

Comment: Is the Regex able to detect them?

Comment: Also 'order by'  is not a word

Comment: Well I Found the problem, I made it wrong, I needed to put the ones with space first before I did the words without any space, now it works fine! :)

Comment: And that's true, but it's still working, and makes it only red after I typed it completely -> `ORDER BY`

Answer (score 1):

In this case you could use the property `FormattedText` of the `Xamarin.Forms.Label`

Example in your case:

```
    private string[] wordsRed = { "Select", "From", "Where"}; // some examples
    private bool isSpecialColor = false;
    private Span span;

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the text changed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">Sender.</param>
    /// <param name="e">E.</param>
    void Handle_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string input = e.NewTextValue;
        string[] qInput = input.Split(' ');

        CheckInput(qInput);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks the input.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="qInput">Q input.</param>
    private void CheckInput(string[] qInput)
    {
        // Check if the last typed character is a word separator.
        if (input[input.Length-1] == ' ') 
        {
            //
            // Loop through the string[] with the words you want to give a color on.
            //
            for (int i = 0; i < wordsRed.Length; i++)
            {
                //
                // Check on the last word that is typed
                //
                if (qInput[qInput.Length-1] == wordsRed[i])
                {
                    // Create a span with the word and color the foreground red
                    span = new Span
                    {
                        Text = qInput[qInput.Length-1] + " ",
                        ForegroundColor = Color.Green,
                    };

                    // Add the span to the Label
                    aLabel.FormattedText.Spans.Add(item: span);
                    // set boolean true because there is made a span with a red foreground.
                    isSpecialColor = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Do nothing.
                }
            }

            // Check if the word altready is colored.
            if (isSpecialColor)
            {
                // Set the boolean to false for the next check.
                isSpecialColor = false;
            }
            else
            {
                // Create span with the word and color it black.
                span = new Span
                {
                    Text = qInput[i] + " ",
                    ForegroundColor = Color.Black,
                };
                aLabel.FormattedText.Spans.Add(item: span);
            }
        }
        else 
        {                
            // Do nothing.
        }
    }
```