# RichTextBox remove color from deleted 'keywords'

Tags: c#, winforms, colors, richtextbox

I've recently found this interesting code that changes the color of the 'key words' in a `RichTextBox` control, from this link [Color specific words in RichtextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21980554/color-specific-words-in-richtextbox)

The problem is that when some letters of the word are deleted, the word is still colored.

eg. keyword is AND and it is red, but if i delete letter N, the remaining letters AD are still red.

I want to able to set it back to the `RichTextBox` `ForeColor`.

I know that I should probably set the `ForeColor` back to white (my default color) before the keywords check, but nothing I tried is working.

Any ideas?

Code by [Sajeetharan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1749403/sajeetharan)

```
private void Rchtxt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.CheckKeyword("and", Color.Red, 0);
        this.CheckKeyword("or", Color.Red, 0);
    }

private void CheckKeyword(string word, Color color, int startIndex)
{
    if (this.Rchtxt.Text.Contains(word))
    {
        int index = -1;
        int selectStart = this.Rchtxt.SelectionStart;

        while ((index = this.Rchtxt.Text.IndexOf(word, (index + 1))) != -1)
        {
            this.Rchtxt.Select((index + startIndex), word.Length);
            this.Rchtxt.SelectionColor = color;
            this.Rchtxt.Select(selectStart, 0);
            this.Rchtxt.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reset the color of complete text to the default color (black in this case) and then run your usual keyword coloring to apply the colors again.

```
    private void Rchtxt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.CheckKeyword(Rchtxt.Text, Color.Black, 0);
        this.CheckKeyword("and", Color.Red, 0);
        this.CheckKeyword("or", Color.Red, 0);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this did the job

Answer (score 1):

Use this answer as a reference for the results:
[How to color different words with different colors in a RichTextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48352623/how-to-color-different-words-with-different-colors-in-a-richtextbox-while-a-user?answertab=active#tab-top)

This class object is used keep track of the words to color and the related color to use when one of these words is written or changed:
(The linked answer explains how to fill the list with words and related colors)

```
public class ColoredWord
{
    public string Word { get; set; }
    public Color WordColor { get; set; }
}

public List<ColoredWord> ColoredWords = new List<ColoredWord>();
```

In the `RichTextBox` `KeyUp()` event, check whether a word in the list is being inserted or modified:
Here I'm using the `KeyUp()` event because at the moment it's raised, the word has already been inserted/modified.

```
private void richTextBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.KeyCode >= Keys.Left & e.KeyCode <= Keys.Down)) return;
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.ShiftKey || e.KeyCode == Keys.Alt || e.KeyCode == Keys.ControlKey) return;

    int CurrentPosition = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
    int[] WordStartEnd;

    string word = GetWordFromPosition(richTextBox1, CurrentPosition - 1, out WordStartEnd);
    ColoredWord result = ColoredWords.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Word == word.ToUpper());
    SetSelectionColor(richTextBox1, result, CurrentPosition, WordStartEnd);

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space && result == null) 
    {
        word = GetWordFromPosition(richTextBox1, CurrentPosition + 1, out WordStartEnd);
        result = ColoredWords.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Word == word.ToUpper());
        SetSelectionColor(richTextBox1, result, CurrentPosition, WordStartEnd);
    }
}
```

These are the helpers methods that are used to color a Word when it's included in the list and to extract the word from the current caret position.

The case when an already colored word is *split* by a space char, thus both ends *lose* their color, is handled in the `KeyUp()` event (the code part is: `if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space && result == null`).

```
private void SetSelectionColor(RichTextBox ctl, ColoredWord word, int Position, int[] WordStartEnd)
{
    ctl.Select(WordStartEnd[0], WordStartEnd[1]);
    if (word != null)
    {
        if (ctl.SelectionColor != word.WordColor)
            ctl.SelectionColor = word.WordColor;
    }
    else
    {
        if (ctl.SelectionColor != ctl.ForeColor)
            ctl.SelectionColor = ctl.ForeColor;
    }
    ctl.SelectionStart = Position;
    ctl.SelectionLength = 0;
    ctl.SelectionColor = richTextBox1.ForeColor;
}

private string GetWordFromPosition(RichTextBox ctl, int Position, out int[] WordStartEnd)
{
    int[] StartEnd = new int[2];
    StartEnd[0] = ctl.Text.LastIndexOf((char)Keys.Space, Position - 1) + 1;
    StartEnd[1] = ctl.Text.IndexOf((char)Keys.Space, Position);
    if (StartEnd[1] == -1) StartEnd[1] = ctl.Text.Length;
    StartEnd[1] -= StartEnd[0];
    WordStartEnd = StartEnd;
    return ctl.Text.Substring(StartEnd[0], StartEnd[1]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful!