# make windows form rich edit text box display text in xml format

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, user-interface

I have a rich text box which is supposed to display some xml text. I want the text to look prettier. Specifically I want it to look like what an xml document looks like in VS or Notepad++, i.e., element names are blue, element values are black, attribute names are red, etc. What's the easiest way to implement this formatting functionality?

Comment: Here's a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087735/a-textbox-richtextbox-that-has-syntax-highlighting-c) that recommends using [ScintillaNET](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/). Incidentally, Notepad++ is based on Scintilla.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Scintilla.NET](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/) is what you are looking for, it has Syntax highlighting support for over 80 languages and does a whole lot more.