# How to Embedd notepad++ in my windows form?

Tags: c#, regex, forms

Embed notepad++ in my windows form. Through which i want to control notepad++ with my own function.

I am using split container.

In panel1--i have a button.
In panel2--notepad++ appear when the form loading.

notepad++ appear on the panel2.

what i am expect is, i use one button in my form.

whenever i click that button, replacing will occur in notepad++ for a single word.

ex, text in notepad++ is,
"This is a file testing for replacing a word in notepad++ through Windows form."

i want to replace a word "This" to "It".
can anyone help me?

Expected Output appear in notepad++ is,
"It is a file testing for replacing a word in notepad++ through Windows form."

So far i did,

Comment: Did you try anything? Show us.

Comment: I actuala had the same idea. With WinApi a lot is possible. It will be kind of a hack. I'm gonna try it actually. But if Notepad++ has its own "hackish" ways it might become very difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do can be achieved differently. Embedding Notepad++ is a wrong idea. It is an independent executable that is not intended to be the "plugin of something"... but is is a great plugin holder itself.

1. Check the Notepad++ [documentation to create your own plugin](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/contribute/plugin-howto.html),
   which will probably be easier and more reliable.
2. If you want to stick with C#, use a dedicated Control to highlight
   some synthax (if it is what you're trying to do), like [Scintilla.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087735/a-textbox-richtextbox-that-has-syntax-highlighting-c).